# how to distinguish os/cpu type in build.gradle ?

Tags: android, build, gradle

How can I distinguish android os or cpu type in build.gradle script ?

I want to include different jave Jar according to different os/cpu type.
Such as if os/cpu is 32 bits then include Jar32, if os/cpu is 64 bits then include Jar64.

Answer (score 5):

You can query the underlaying system architecture via

```
def arch = System.getProperty("os.arch")
```

and use `arch` in your build script to make your required distinctions